# Finish many activities at once

Tags: android, android-activity

Im developing an iOS app for Android and I'm facing a problem. In the Android app, there is a time where the user will navigate from one of the main tabs to 5 activities one after the other, like a navigation app, but when i get to the 5th activity and completes a task, i need to finish all the 5 actives and go back to the main tab activity. How would i do that?

In iOS i would simply `popToRootViewController` and thats it.. but in android there is no such a thing, that i know of.

Thanks,
Newton

Edit #1: Im supporting Android 2.2 and I am using the SherlockBar Library.

Comment: If there's no moving backwards in your activity chain, each activity could simply `finish()` after starting the next. Otherwise you would have them start the next activity "for result" and finish() after receiving the right result.

Comment: @mah thanks for the reply.. but i can't simply finish each activity before start the next one because the user might want to go back and change something and then go forward again..

Comment: per expected Android app design, that's not really a good reason to not finish() early. As a well written Android activity, you're required to be able to save your state and resume it on little notice, in response to being paused/resumed (which happens when the activity is changed, when the home button is pressed, when power is removed, etc.) -- so you're saying you can't do the very thing you're already supposed to be able to do? No law says you must do it of course, but if you were prepared to do what Android design calls for, your task here would be easier.

Comment: I do save the activity state before leaving it and i could indeed finish it after i leave it.. but then i would have to watch for the back pressed method to launch the previous activity every time.. as noted by @Darkhogg i think I'm going to start the first activity with that flag so all the top activities will be finished at once… I will try it as soon as i can and then i will accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch an intent to your root activity using [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: but wouldn't it just create another instance of my tab bar activity?

Comment: oh no.. i just read this flag docs and it looks promising.. i will try this and the other altenartives.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `NavUtils` helper class for this, which manages proper navigation per the Android Design Guide. You can simply call the [`navigateUpTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NavUtils.html#navigateUpTo%28android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent%29) method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
```

For further uses of this class, check out the [navigation guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer is correct, but since i didn't use NavUtils from the beginning, it would take a lot of effort to update all 5 activities to use it.. so i thought that @Darkhogg's answer was more appropriate to my situation!

Comment: Actually, `NavUtils` does the same as @Darkhogg answer on pre Jelly Bean devices:

`@Override public void navigateUpTo(Activity activity, Intent upIntent)
    { upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); activity.startActivity(upIntent); activity.finish(); }`

On JB and up, it calls `activity.navigateUpTo`.